# Lambda can not access RDS though those are in the same VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

I have created `VPC` and `RDS` with the below `CloudFormation`.

```
Resources:
  TestVpc:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::VPC"
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: "10.0.0.0/16"
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
  TestSubnetA:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::Subnet"
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: "ap-northeast-1a"
      CidrBlock: "10.0.0.0/20"
      VpcId: !Ref TestVpc
  TestSubnetB:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::Subnet"
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: "ap-northeast-1d"
      CidrBlock: "10.0.16.0/20"
      VpcId: !Ref TestVpc
  TestSubnetC:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::Subnet"
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: "ap-northeast-1c"
      CidrBlock: "10.0.32.0/20"
      VpcId: !Ref TestVpc
  TestSecurityGroup:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup"
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: "Test security group with cloduformation"
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - CidrIp: "10.0.0.0/16"
          IpProtocol: "tcp"
          FromPort: 0
          ToPort: 65535
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - CidrIp: "0.0.0.0/0"
          FromPort: 0
          ToPort: 65535
          IpProtocol: "tcp"
      VpcId: !Ref TestVpc

  TestSubnetGroup:
    Type: "AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup"
    Properties:
      DBSubnetGroupDescription: "TestSubnetGroupDesc"
      SubnetIds:
        - !Ref TestSubnetA
        - !Ref TestSubnetB
        - !Ref TestSubnetC

  TestRDS:
    Type: "AWS::RDS::DBInstance"
    Properties:
      DBInstanceClass: "db.t2.micro"
      DBInstanceIdentifier: "rekog-moderation"
      DBName: "rekog"

      Engine: "postgres"
      EngineVersion: "10.4"

      MasterUsername: "rekog"
      MasterUserPassword: "passwd"
      AllocatedStorage: "20"

      DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref TestSubnetGroup
      VPCSecurityGroups:
        - !Ref TestSecurityGroup
```

---

## The result of RDS

[image]

---

## Lambda setting

[image]

---

When `Lambda` try to access with Domain name `rekog-moderation.cokqwd6ixsnc.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com`, it returns timeout error while making a connection to `RDS`.

What do I miss?

Comment: Put a debug statement in your Lambda code to [resolve the DNS name of the Amazon RDS instance to an IP address](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/python/dns-lookup-python). The intention is that is falls in the `10.x.x.x` IP range, which means it will communicate purely within the VPC. Also, can you add the relevant Lambda code to your Question?

Comment: @John Rotenstein, Many thank you for your comment again, As I debug lambda code, It was because of access to `Rekognition` in `VPC`. I should have set `NAT gateway` for lambda to access resources outside the `VPC`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add security group self-reference in ingress rule, in order to allow all members of security group to communicate with each other. Something like:

```
"TestSecurityGroupIngress": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
  "Properties": {
    "GroupId": { "Ref": "TestSecurityGroup" },
    "IpProtocol": "tcp",
    "FromPort": "0",
    "ToPort": "65535",
    "SourceSecurityGroupId": { "Ref": "TestSecurityGroup" }
  }
}
```

You can find more info on self referencing security group in CF on [AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=245655)

Comment: It won't let me edit just a typo, but last sentence should be "You can find more info".

Answer (score 0):

Besides of @caldazar answer:

I had similar issue while using `mysql` npm package. In the process of debugging I've tried to see what ip address does the hostname resolve to with:

```
const { lookup: lc } = require('dns');
const { promisify } = require('util');

const lookup = promisify(lc);
const { address } = await lookup('<my-hostname.com>');
```

Then I've checked that IP address was in the range specified for the RDS instance and subnets and it matched availability zone.

Problem was that `mysql` was trying to resolve the hostname from public DNS probably. So rather than passing the hostname I've just passed the resolved IP address into the initialization of mysql and it worked.